Databricks merge operation throws LOCATION_OVERLAP error
I am trying to persist data into a delta table using a scheduled notebook which reads daily from an Postgres DB. I want to make sure no duplicates are stored so I perform a merge operation with new data:
delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path)

(delta_table
    .alias("target")
    .merge(
        remote_df.alias("source"),
        "target.time = source.time AND target.devicename = source.devicename")  # Define the unique key condition here
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll()  # Update all values when the condition matches
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()  # Insert new rows when there is no match
    .execute()
)   

I created an external location in S3 (s3://databricks-managed-location) beforehand und made sure that the catalog and schema are created accordingly
create_catalog_sql = f"CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS catalog123 MANAGED LOCATION 's3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123';" 
create_schema_sql = f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS catalog123.myschema MANAGED LOCATION 's3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123';"

The table is initially created via
remote_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f"catalog123.myschema.mytable")

The error I receive is
Input path url 's3://databricks-managed-location/project123' overlaps with managed storage within 'CheckPathAccess' call. .

Update:
So I changed it to
create_catalog_sql = f"CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS catalog123 MANAGED LOCATION 's3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123';" 
create_schema_sql = f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS catalog123.myschema"

But the error persistes
's3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123' overlaps with managed storage within 'CheckPathAccess' call. .

Update 2:
so this works
create_catalog_sql = f"CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS catalog123 MANAGED LOCATION 's3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123';" 
create_schema_sql = f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema"

But now myschema is not placed under catalog123 but under the hive_metastore catalog which seems to be the default if I dont specify one

Your catalog location:
s3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123

clearly overlaps with schema location (is the same actually):
s3://databricks-managed-location/catalog123

When you define a location for a catalog Databricks wants to have it exclusively. There can be no other catalog or schema under any path with the given prefix.
These examples are fine:
CREATE CATALOG c       MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;

CREATE CATALOG c       MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA myschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/myschema;

All of these are NOT fine:
CREATE CATALOG c         MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA c.myschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;

CREATE CATALOG c         MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA c.myschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123/myschema;

CREATE CATALOG c         MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA c.myschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/myschema;
CREATE SCHEMA c.xxschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/myschema/xx;

CREATE CATALOG c         MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA c.myschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/c123/x/y/z/myschema;

CREATE CATALOG c         MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/myschema/c123;
CREATE SCHEMA c.myschema MANAGED LOCATION s3://d-m-l/myschema;


see my update above
